# what is a spatial variable? I do not know what it means

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

What is a spatial variable? Can anyone provide an example and clear definition?
I can't seem to find any clear definitions or examples. For example, why can't a certain equation rely on the spatial variable of t?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to answer without a bit more context, but I would think it refers to a variable in some kind of model, which represents some form of displacement or distance (or maybe its derivatives, like velocity or acceleration). As opposed to a temporal variable, which represents time (often denoted $t$). If you want an answer beyond that, you'll need to provide the specific text where you encountered this phrase.

Comment: A spatial variable is literally just that; a variable (usually $x,y,z$ or $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ etc) that describes a spatial dimension. A temporal variable (usually $t$ or $\tau$) is a variable that describes the temporal dimension. You can can use any letter or symbol you like to describe the different dimensions i.e a spatial variable could be denoted by $a$ or $\gamma$ or $t$ or what ever other symbol you like. The reason why we use, say, $x$ for space and not $t$ is partly for clarity (it is much more obvious to let $t$ refer to _time_ than _space_) and partly due to convention.

Comment: As a matter of fact there are some formulas relevant to differential equations (for example, Runge-Kutta methods) in which some authors use $t$ for a variable that could be either temporal or spatial, depending on how you apply the formula to a problem with spatial and temporal dimensions. In that sense, an equation **can** rely on the spatial variable of $t.$ If someone is telling you it cannot, perhaps if you give a more complete account of what they told you, someone here can explain what it meant (and whether it is even correct).